# Why does PHP's filter_var not recognize an email address?

Tags: php

I am starting with PHP and wrote a unit tests to see if I get things right.

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyTest extends TestCase {
    public function testEmailWtf() {
        $this->assertTrue(filter_var("me@gmail.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
    }
}
?>
```

This fails, but I don't understand why.

> 1) MyTest::testEmailWtf
>
> Failed asserting that 'me@gmail.com' is true.

Why does this not accept a valid email address?

Comment: `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` does not return a boolean.

Comment: `Return Values: Returns the filtered data, or FALSE if the filter fails.`

Comment: @mario Thanks, you're right, I did not read the manual carefully enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php, `filter_var` will return `FALSE` if something is wrong, or return *your string* if everything's ok.

So I believe you should change your test with `assertEquals` :

```
<?php
$emailToValidate = "me@gmail.com";
$this->assertEquals($emailToValidate , filter_var($emailToValidate, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));
?>
```

Comment: I'd probably also add another assertion `$this->assertSame("me@gmail.com", filter_var("me@gmail.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));` to make sure it returns what I think it should